# Laravel Model count is not updating values

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

i have been working on laravel project and there is a place where i need to count all table values  i used $allUsers=USERS::count(); it was working fine but suddenly this query is not working and its also returning 30 the place where it was before month. Here is my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class USERSS extends Model
{
    public $table = "user_data";

    //
    protected $fillable = [
       'id',  'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'
    ];

}
```

here is my controller which is not updating
$totalusers = USERSS::count();

its not updating values.

Comment: What error ? your getting

Comment: Is your model name  correct??

Comment: what you actually want ? your question is not clear.

Comment: i need to count number of users in database.@Kamlesh Paul

Comment: can u show the controller's full code? what do you mean by not updating the value? is it return an old value or?

Comment: @Khalid i can understand but what error ? your getting ?

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul no error it just shows me 30.

Comment: then check your database how many is there

Comment: @WailanTirajoh  weeks ago there are 30 users and its counting correctly. Now i have around 70. it returns only 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you already try

```
USERSS::count()
```

and the result comes wrong.

have you tried [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-all-rows-from-a-table)?

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
dd(DB::table('user_data')->count());
```

Comment: Ive heard that if youre using Query Builder, you cant use eloquent relation in there. just use it wisely.